# Can we use a spring cloud based micro service running in multiple nodes as SCDF applications?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am newbie in SCDF. I have few micro services running behind Spring Cloud platform. Each services got multiple nodes. Can we use those existing services into SCDF platform as either SOURCE, PROCESSOR or SINK? If so, how would I get them into dashboard as they are already deployed as services!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCDF doesn't probe on a given K8s cluster/namespace to automatically build the streaming data pipelines.

Today, it is imperative that the [streaming](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/data-flow-stream/#creating-the-stream-definition)/[task](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/data-flow-composed-task/) "definitions" are created and deployed in SCDF first, and only then it is possible to monitor, scale, and manage the applications.

In case it wasn't apparent already, SCDF can *only* orchestrate the deployment and the management for event-streaming and batch/task Spring Boot applications. Not all kinds of application workloads are possible.